# Start Django with different setting values

Tags: python, django

I am writing test for my Django app. I want to start Django with different settings value and run tests for each case. (eg one test for settings.ALLOW_ROBOTS=True and another test for settings.ALLOW_ROBOTS=False). I am not interested in overriding the value at run time. I want to start the server with different settings value each time. Does Django provide a way to accomplish this?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The tests are run automatically in Travis CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which settings.py file to use with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`; you can have many that import * from a main one, and then change what needs to be changed.

Alternatively, settings.py is just a Python file. You can get values of settings from environment variables, if you want:

```
import os

ALLOW_ROBOTS = bool(os.getenv('ALLOW_ROBOTS', False))
```

And then change that environment variable from Travis.

Comment: Thanks. os.getenv did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to be able to use multiple settings modules. If so, setting the [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) environment variable before starting the server is likely what you need.